# Looping an array from form element

Tags: php, forms, loops, variables, post

hope you can help me on this..

i have this simple code :

```
foreach ($by_sellers as $seller_id => $info) {
  print_r($info);
  echo 'AMOUNT : ' . $info['total'] .'; STORE : '. $info['name'];
}
```

and the output is this :

```
Array(
  ['total'] => 100
  ['name'] => 'Store Name'
)
AMOUNT : ; STORE :
```

its really weird coz i cant read the values of the variable if done individually but it display on var_dump & print_r.. those data comes from input forms..

```
<input name="by_sellers[1]['total']" value="100">
<input name="by_sellers[1]['name']" value="Store Name">
```

hope someone find the light on this problem.. thanx..

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/gsMqM). There has to be more to this than what you're showing. Can you include a sample of `$by_sellers`?

Comment: also maybe your name is wrong in your input? you have not used php tags or listed it as a variable with $, therefore your 'name' will just be directly 'by_sellers[1]['total']' rather than the value of

Comment: Aah, took me some time to catch. You shouldn't use single quotes inside HTML when defining the index or it will become a part of the index. Change `by_sellers[1]['total']` to `by_sellers[1][total]`, same for any others.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanx.. i already found it before i read your comment.. hehehe..

Answer (score 0):

found the solution and its a simple one..

i just edit the html code from this

```
<input name="by_sellers[1]['total']" value="100">
<input name="by_sellers[1]['name']" value="Store Name">
```

to this (**removing the quotes of the string name**)

```
<input name="by_sellers[1][total]" value="100">
<input name="by_sellers[1][name]" value="Store Name">
```